# OpenGL ES function

Tags: opengl-es

how to set the coordinate in openGL ES? I have import my 3D object in openGL ES then I use gltranslatef (x,y,z) to translate the object. However, may I ask how to set the coordinate of the 3d object? any API of OpenGL? not using gltranslate because gltranslate just make the simple translation of object. But then, I want the user key in the x axis value and y axis value to make the 3d object go to that position.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

glTranslate is what you want, there's no other function that does the same, and it's the correct way of moving an object.

Comment: I know and I have used the glTranslate to move my object. But after I have moved my object, I want to know the exact coordinate of my object, so how to know it? :) thanks

Comment: There is no direct way, you can apply manually the transformation to your vertices to get the same data on the CPU.

Comment: I think I can't apply manually toward my vertices because I have imported my 3D object from maya and the 3D object convert to vertices..Thus, there is too much vertices ( more than thousand of vertices) , so I not even know which vertices I need to identify. Thanks..:)